# Mouse sensitivity in games

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

I have been gaming on my system lately. I have never encountered this problem before and all the google research never worked. Here are the specs of my machine :

---

CPU/APU : AMD A8-6600K Black Edition @ 3.9 GHz
RAM : 4GB DDR3 @ 1333 MHz
GPU : Galaxy Nvidia GeForce GT620 w/ 2GB DDR3 RAM for video
HDD : 1 TB WD Caviar Blue
PSU : Corsair CX430 430W

---

I have tried many different games, online , browser , fps , tps , etc. The mouse works fine but then when I move my character and then move my mouse, the slightest of movements cause the game to freak out. How do I fix this ?
EDIT : The mouse is not the problem. I changed mice and tried my mouse no another computer, so the mouse is not the problem

Comment: Have you looked at the mouse configurations in the control panel of your computer? Also, have you updated your mouse and keyboard drivers?

Comment: Also, make sure that your game or fullscreen application is at the correct resolution.

Comment: @TheBird956 I am running the latest drivers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a general hardware issue.  As stated, this is not limited to games, so this is not a gaming-specific issue.  You may get a solution to your issues at SuperUser.

Comment: @Frank i think its not, it says in topics that can be asked are `Game-specific hardware and utilities`, and im seeing this question as a game specific question.

Comment: @ken According to what the user has reported, this problem isn't specific to games.  That's how I determined that it's not a problem specific to games.  I'm not sure where game-specific hardware and utilities even comes into the equation.

Comment: @Frank Where does the user say this isn't game specific?

Comment: Take a look at the last paragraph: "I have tried many different games, online , browser , fps , tps , etc"  Browsers are pretty windows based items, and if the mouse is freaking out in that, chances are extremely good this isn't a gaming issue.  It's a general hardware issue.

Comment: @Frank This isn't a hardware issue because I have a few spare mice and tried them out. That still didn't change anything.

Comment: It's not just mice that are hardware.  It could be your OS, or something in your computer itself that is the issue.  The symptoms you've described point to something wrong with your computer, not a configuration issue in a game.  That's what SuperUser is for.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite a common problem which is resolved by running Minecraft in Windows 7 compatibility mode:

[image]

Comment: I try this and see what happens.

Comment: That didn't work :-(